# Ng-repeat only showing the first value of Json object

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I'm having a problem with ng-repeat only showing the first json object
this is my html:

```
    <table class="table minerva-table  table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Allergies</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in info track by $index">{{value}}</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

this is my js controller

```
Object.toparams = function ObjecttoParams(obj) {
    var p = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
    }
    return p.join('&');
};


angular.module('mainApp')
    .controller('AllergiesController', ['$scope', '$http',
            function AllergiesController($scope, $http)
            {

                $scope.errorMsg = false;
                $scope.info=[];
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "php/medical_getAllergies.php",
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                }).then(
                    //SUCCESS
                    function (result) {
                        var data = result.data;

                        if (data.status === "ok") {
                            $scope.info = data.data[0];
                        }
                        else
                            $scope.errorMsg = data.errorMsg;
                    },
                    //ERROR
                    function (error) {
                        $scope.errorMsg = error;
                    }
                );

            }

        ]
    );
```

and this is the object it is receiving from the php file

```
{
    "data": [{
        "AllergyType": "ASA1234",
        "AllergyNote": "test"
    }, {
        "AllergyType": "Ceclor",
        "AllergyNote": "test"
    }],
    "status": "ok",
    "errorMsg": ""
}
```

Only the first AllergyType and AllergyNote is showing, I tried adding `ng-repeat-start` and I tried adding a nested `ng-repeat` so I'm not quite sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Change `$scope.info = data.data[0];` to `$scope.info = data.data`

Comment: unfortunately that didn't seem to work

Comment: Still doesn't work, yeah for what ever reason when I try to specifiy .AllergyType or .AllergyNote nothing comes up at all

Comment: Check this example: https://embed.plnkr.co/BDP8K8bzV5QmaApUsGkq/

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is DOM structure issue, just replace following code 
`<tbody>
            <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in info track by $index">{{value}}</td>
        </tbody>` with

```
<tbody><tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in info track by $index">
                    <td>{{value.AllergyType}}</td>
                    <td>{{value.AllergyNote}}</td>
                </tr></tbody>`
```

Comment: To add more clarification now its just showing a blank table

Answer (score 0):

It is showing first record beacause you are accessing `$scope.info = data.data[0];` first record, please find below working code:

```js
Object.toparams = function ObjecttoParams(obj) {
    var p = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
    }
    return p.join('&');
};
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.info1 = {
    "data": [{
        "AllergyType": "ASA1234",
        "AllergyNote": "test"
    }, {
        "AllergyType": "Ceclor",
        "AllergyNote": "test"
    }],
    "status": "ok",
    "errorMsg": ""
}
$scope.info = $scope.info1.data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <table class="table minerva-table  table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Allergies</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in info">
                    <td>{{value.AllergyType}}</td>
                    <td>{{value.AllergyNote}}</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```